# JSON parsing with jquery displaying specific nodes

Tags: jquery, json

I am having some difficulties parsing this JSON output which I am getting from a request. What I am trying to accomplish is to show two types of outputs.

**I would like to only show *USER1 "change" and "time"* attributes.**

**I would like to show *all users "change" and "time" and "date"* attributes.**

Here is what the json looks like.

```
[
{"@attributes":
    {"name":"USER1","last":"72.34","change":"-0.04","sum":"-0.06","volume":"963188","height":"74.69","low":"58.68","date":"Mar 10 2014","time":"04:00"}
},
{"@attributes":
    {"name":"USER2","last":"63.98","change":"0.37","sum":"0.58","volume":"1191173","height":"66.75","low":"55.1","date":"Mar 10 2014","time":"04:00"}
},
{"@attributes":
    {"name":"USER3","last":"94.56","change":"0.62","sum":"0.66","volume":"1136925","height":"94.86","low":"73.89","date":"Mar 10 2014","time":"04:00"}
}
]
```

Can someone help me get started with how to approach this? Would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ajax for this problem. try this one my friend

**only show USER1 "change" and "time" attributes**

```
formData = {
    name: "USER1"
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://example.com/detail.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.@attributes[0].change);
        console.log(data.@attributes[0].time);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

**show all users "change" and "time" and "date" attributes.**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://example.com/all.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.@attributes, function(index, item) {
             console.log(item.change);
             console.log(item.time);
             console.log(item.date);
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

Done!!